# How do you test a sequence of random variables for independence?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

So I have a sequence of random variables and I'd like to use a theorem that requires them to be iid. I've got the identically distributed part. But I'm unsure about independence. Is there any such thing as "almost independent"? If so, how could one test this empirically?

Comment: Are they discrete?

Comment: No. But they are restricted to the interval $[0,1]$.